# Two AVplayers in a scrollView play delay

Tags: ios, media-player

I've got two AVPlayers playing two halves of a 2048px wide movie. I need them synchronised, because there are objects moving from one to another. However I always get a small delay (I can't really think of the way to measure this delay) between AVPlayers starting to play.
Here is the code I use.

```
-(void) addMovieToViewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSURL *theMovieLeftURL = nil;
    NSURL *theMovieRightURL = nil;

if (bundle) 
 {
  NSString *movieLeftPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"left_video" ofType:@"mp4"];

  if (movieLeftPath)
  {   
    theMovieLeftURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:movieLeftPath];
  }
 }      

if (bundle) 
{
    NSString *movieRightPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"right_video" ofType:@"mp4"];

    if (movieRightPath)
    {   
        theMovieRightURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:movieRightPath];
    }
}    

AVPlayer* player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:theMovieLeftURL];
AVPlayer* rightPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:theMovieRightURL];


AVPlayerLayer* layerLeft = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
AVPlayerLayer* layerRight = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:rightPlayer];

[layerLeft setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
[layerRight setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];

//layerLeft.frame = [self.scrollView viewWithTag:tag].bounds;
NSInteger ntag = tag+1;

[[self.scrollView viewWithTag:tag].layer addSublayer:layerLeft];
[[self.scrollView viewWithTag:ntag].layer addSublayer:layerRight];


//[self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
CMTime delay= CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(10, 1);
[rightPlayer play];

    [player play];
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(1024, 0 ) animated:NO];




self.timeObserver = [player addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:delay]]   queue:NULL usingBlock:^{
    [self setTimeObserver:nil];
    [self doAnimatedScrollTo:CGPointMake(0, 0)];


}];

}
```

I wonder If I'm doing something wrong with it. I assume that there is a delay between rightPlayer starts to play and a player, however I can't figure out how to eliminate it.
I tried to use seekToTime: with small delay, but It's really tough to find a proper delay.
Is it possible to have them playing simultaneously at all?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you probably will never be able to get them to sync up exactly. If you require absolute perfect precision you're going to need to approach this from a much lower level. The `AVPlayer` class just isn't designed for perfect synch on playback.